# tcp ip checking i missing something

Tags: c, tcp, header, port

I am using winpcap driver to sniff packets,
so I actually using the example of packet dump inside it to get the pkt_data etc ,

when i processing the tcp header I printing my port and i see it 80

but when i trying to make something like:

```
  if(ntohl(tcpheader->source_port == 80) || (ntohl(tcpheader->dest_port == 80))) //doesnt work :(
{
    printf("****************HTTP***********");
}
```

the if is never true 
but i clearly see in my printf

```
printf(" |-Source Port : %u\n",ntohs(tcpheader->source_port));
printf(" |-Destination Port : %u\n",ntohs(tcpheader->dest_port));
```

one of them is 80 in my output , but i never see the ***http*** from above , so seems i am missing something could you please point me ?

Comment: You should be calling ntohs(), not ntohl(). Port numbers are 16 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(ntohl(tcpheader->source_port == 80) ...
```

You're converting the *result of the comparison*

You need to compare the result of the conversion and 80:

```
if (ntohs(tcpheader->source_port) == 80) ...
```

Comment: Guys i changed it , but i still cant see the print of http

Comment: update your Q with how you have it now - if the `printf` outputs `80` there's still something wrong. (Also, note that you don't have a `\n` in your "http" `printf` which means it won't flush).

Comment: I added \n and queue updates in real time, i stoping it to see the particular packet , and still nothing .

I thinking that ntohl returns u_long and 80 "as is" is integer, but as far as i know c should auto convert it not ?

Comment: well i tried everything it does prints that port is 80 but if is never true :()

Comment: Without more context I can't really offer anything. If you set a breakpoint prior to the `if` in the debugger, what's in `tcpheader`? For that matter, what *is* `tcpheader` ?

Comment: emm the message is too long , where to put it ?

Comment: oh here i uses as same as they do 

http://www.binarytides.com/code-packet-sniffer-c-winpcap/

Comment: No, you aren't using the same code at all. Take another look.

Comment: if `source_port` and `dest_port` are `unsigned short` ... why are you using `ntohl()`? That ... kinda makes a difference ;)

Comment: damn I got it !!

it should be ntohS
not ntohl ... 

well thanks now it works !!! and as I feel myself dumb enough now ,
i think time to sleep .
thanks everyone for help !

Comment: That was wrong but it wasn't the actual problem at all. The problem was the operator precedence caused by your incorrect placement of the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ntohl(tcpheader->source_port == 80)` you should write `ntohl(tcpheader->source_port) == 80`. Otherwise you `ntohl` the result of comparison and not the port number.

Comment: Thank you guys, i watching it for 30 minutes (3 am here)
and i cant get what is wrong :)